# Python: converting single digit decimal to hex

Tags: python, hex, digit

Is there any way to get `hex (5)` output `'0x05'` instead of `'0x5'`?

For example i want to convert `[255,11,132]` to hex string like `'ff0b84'` So i can slice it by 2 characters and covert to decimal again. But python doesn't put `0` before `b` so i can't slice string by 2 characters!

Comment: `def hex(_): return '0x05'`.  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) to get '0x05' instead of '0x5':

```
In [64]: format(5, '#04x')
Out[64]: '0x05'

In [65]: format(15, '#04x')
Out[65]: '0x0f'
```

Comment: Thanks.Just for more information what '#04x' means?

Comment: @HBS. Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) how formatting works.